# How to use external JS with parameters in component in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

Let's say you have an external js that has some parameters **that you generate**, like datetime/etc, and the result looks like this `'http://example.com/example.aspx?lang=en&amp;displaylanguage=true&amp;time=9:00 AM'`

**None working example**

```
ngOnInit() {
  let s = document.createElement("script");
  s.id = "exampleScript";
  s.type = "text/javascript";
  s.src = "http://example.com/example.aspx?lang=en&amp;displaylanguage=true&amp;time=9:00 AM";
  document.getElementById("some-id").appendChild(s);
}
```

How do you use this on your component?

Comment: what do you mean by using in component you can make `service`

Comment: @WasiqMuhammad does a service add `<script id="exampleScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/example.aspx?lang=en&amp;displaylanguage=true&amp;time=9:00 AM"></script>` to your component, that works?

Comment: its not the correct way as you are requesting some resource on server use `$http` and pass data in `params` and using that service in component `@Input`